# How to make `C-x C-k` dictionary completion respect case?

Tags: autocompletion

Vim has excellent inbuilt autocompletions. I've noticed that using `C-x C-k` (see `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K` for more) for dictionary completion will not respect the case by default.

For instance, if I type `Carr`, Vim might suggest `carrot` instead of `Carrot`. Is there a way to have vim respect case (or at least offer to respect case) with dictionary autocompletion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding:

```
set smartcase
```

to your `vimrc` should fix your problem

Comment: `infercase` could also be set, I think. Ah, but it implies `ignorecase`.